# How to assign hardcode value to Invoke Activity in BPEL

Tags: wso2, bpel, apache-ode, jboss-esb

I have a if condition and need to invoke the service with hard-code argument when the condition satisfies.

How to assign the hard code value to the invoke activity.

Is there any book, tutorials, documents available which cover everything about BPEL.

Answer (score 0):

For assigning values and all other kinds of data operations, BPEL offers the assign activity. 
Assign can copy from a "literal", i.e. some constant XML to a variable. The variable is then used in the invoke activity as the input variable.

For the concrete syntax see the first example on the Apache ODE documentation page: https://ode.apache.org/assign.html

Hope this helps!